# ModuleNotFoundError when run from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, module, pycharm

I used `import nmap` module from python-nmap, and it works fine in Pycharm.

But when I try to run the same program on command prompt, it gives error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nmap'

pip is installed in the directory path `pycharmprojects\botnet\venv\lib\site-packages (0.6.1)`. This is the same path where my program is located.

Has anyone seen this error?

It doesn't work in `cmd` instead of Pycharm.
[image: in cmd not working in pycharm everything works fine//]

Pycharm terminal says it's installed in the path where it should be installed.
[image: //pycharm terminal says its installed in the path where it should be installed i guess..]

Comment: try activating your virtual environment. `pycharmprojects\botnet\venv\bin\activate.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first image, you don't have your virtual environment activated. Because you only have `python-nmap` installed in your virtual environment python, your system-wide python installation can't find it.

In the second image, you do have the virtual environment activated, which is why it says python-nmap is installed.

To activate your virtual environment on Windows, you need to execute `\path\to\your\venv\bin\activate.exe`. Then run your command and it should work.

Alternatively, you could just run `pip install python-nmap` to install it on your system level python installation.